# How do I use a regular expression to match all numbers after a certain character until it reaches another character

Tags: javascript, regex

So, I've got this problem: I'm making a scientific calculator in javascript I need to match all numbers after a certain character (say !) until it reaches another character. So say if the regular expression was to validate this: `1+2*3+100!` I want everything after the `!` until it reaches ANY other character (like the `+`). So the value returned would be `100`. I have no idea where to even start with this as I have never used regular expressions before.

Please help :)

Comment: *"I have no idea where to even start with this as I have never used regular expressions before."* How about start by learning about regular expressions.

Comment: Why are you using regex? Is `!` supposed to be a factorial? If so, what do you mean by returning `100` if your intention is to match everything after `!` until it reaches `ANY other character` (which is vague. Do you mean any other operator?)

Comment: @remyabel: Yes, ! is the factorial. I am making a calculator. I want all of the equation to be put in a text-box so I can eval it, but eval doesn't support the ! symbol so I have to replace it and the numbers before it before using eval, thus calculating the factorial with a script. I am using regex to find the bits that this other script will use. So I only want the 100, not the +, *, /, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should do the trick: `\d+(?=!)`

Match minimum 1 but as much as possible \d numbers that are followed by a !

Comment: OP wants to match all characters *after* the `!` until another certain character is matched.

Comment: Even though he uses the word after, from what he needs it seems like he meant the word before!